# function triggering before value is given

Tags: c++, getline, stringstream

The name for this question might be bad, as I have no idea what is going on here. But I have this function called `str2int()` that checks if a user input value is a number. And for whatever reason, it triggers before any input is given.
This is a were it is called in my `main()`:

```
  std::string stringSKILL;
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    switch(i) {
      case 0:
        cout <<"\n\nStrength (How strong you are)";
        cout <<"\nHow many points (you have " << total_SKILL_points << " left): ";
        std::getline(std::cin,stringSKILL);
        Strength = str2int(stringSKILL);
        if(str2int_i == 0) {
          Strength = 0;
          i--;
          str2int_i++;
          break;
// }'s later in program
```

And this is the function:

```
// Check if user input is a number
int str2int(std::string &str) {
  std::stringstream ss(str);
  int num;
  ss >> num;
  if(ss) { // error handling
    return num;
  }
  else {
    cout <<"\n\nPlease Enter a Number!";
    str2int_i--;
  }
}
```

But when this program is ran, the "Please enter a number" has been printed without any input given. After that, it all works fine. 
Why is this?

Comment: try `std::cin.ingore()` after `std::getline()`

Comment: What did you observe in debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your buffer after getline to prevent whatever value is in the buffer to be used as input (likely a newline)

```
std::getline(std::cin,stringSKILL);
std::cin.ingore()
```

Should solve it. Otherwise, you should post the rest of your code!